# Elm main function type annotation

Tags: elm

What is the meaning of this Elm example's main function type annotation?

```
main : Html msg
main =
    div [] [ text "1" ]
```

What is Html and msg?

Comment: This is explained [in the guide](https://guide.elm-lang.org/types/reading_types.html) too, although not in as much detail as the answer below But you really should read it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First of all, that one is not a function, because it doesn't take any parameter.

However, type annotation is saying that the `main` is of type `Html` with a not yet known variant `msg`.

`Html` is the type, like `Int` or `String`, and `msg` is the type variant.

Some types can have variants, take `List a` as an example.

`List a` means that you are declaring a `List` where the type variant is irrelevant or not yet known. For instance, the type annotation for `List.length` method is:

```
length : List a -> Int
```

When you'll use this method, you'll certainly have a type instead of `a`, like `String` or `Int` or whatever, by the behaviour of `length` doesn't change.

Don't be confused then by the `msg` addition to `Html`. It has the same meaning. In Elm you render html code that may dispatch some messages, and you usually define them as a union type like:

```
type Msg
  = ClickedSave
  | EnteredText String
```

So, your main declaration can remain `Html msg`, or `Html a` until you dispatch a message.

If you, for instance, add an `onClick` handler to your `div` like:

```
main =
    div [ onClick ClickedSave ] [ text "1" ]
```

the type annotation becomes (whether you annotate it or not) `Html Msg`, because now the message you are dispatching is of type `Msg`.

Hope it's clear, and sorry for my english, it's not my native language.

Comment: Good answer. One thing is unclear though: You say "that one is not a function, because it doesn't take any parameter". Why such a limitation? Functions can only return values, inputs are not mandatory.

Comment: If there are no input parameters, it's just a variable (a constant actually). Am I missing your point maybe?

Comment: In a curried language, a function has exactly one argument. A function taking multiple arguments is just syntax sugar for a function returning another function and so on, each taking a single argument. But no such sugar is possible for a "function" with no arguments since there must be at least one. So you're technically correct that it's not a function, but it does seem a bit pedantic to point out what's effectively an implementation detail in a pure language.

Comment: Great comments! I have always though, in addition to what glennsl mentioned about currying, that `main` is a function that only returns a value. But now this got me to challenge that thought (which is a good thing), since without side effects, such function can be replaced with its value. Fancy term is referential transparency. Now the discussion is going wildly off topic...

Comment: This doesn't seem to be correct.

Html in Elm is a function.